# Is there a built-in method for Chrome Extensions to poll the subscription information?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

We're trying to setup a referral tracking program for a chrome extension we developed. To track reoccurring subscriptions we'd like to be able to poll the Subscription Status and I was able to find `google.payments.inapp.getPurchases` in their documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#get-purchases

I was wondering if it was possible to poll for the order number associated with the purchase. This seems to be a way to uniquely tie and track a user to a subscription and also lets us correlate the info available on [pay.google.com](https://pay.google.com)

Any suggestions or information is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this [blogpost](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-chrome-extension-for-real-time-price-tracking-with-appbase)?

Answer (score 0):

Response I got back from the Chrome Developer Support:

> Thank you for contacting Chrome Web Store Developer Support! In
>   regards to your question, unfortunately, we are not supporting polling
>   the associated order number at the time. However, I absolutely agree
>   with you that it would be very helpful for our developers in the CWS.
>   I'll be glad to convey your message to the pertinent team to discuss
>   this topic.